# When changing height of html textbox, rest of page gets crowded

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Some of the fields on my form can be multi-line, including, for example, the "comments" field.  Notice the spacing on the fields after the comments are all ok.

[image]

because the users can enter multi-line text, I have added the following code to the page, so that it will resize the field appropriately.  Basically just handle the "OnKeyUp" event on the textbox to resize it so that its display height is equal to its scroll height.

```
    function AutoExpandTextbox(txtbox) {
        txtbox.style.height = "1px";
        txtbox.style.height = (4 + txtbox.scrollHeight) + "px";
        ResizeFormGroup(txtbox);
    }
    ....
    <div class="form-group">
        <asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="commentsTextBox" CssClass="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 control-label">Comments</asp:Label>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
            <asp:TextBox ID="commentsTextBox" onkeyup="javascript: AutoExpandTextbox(this);"  class="form-control input-sm input-full-width" runat="server" MaxLength="255" TextMode="MultiLine"  />
```

But even though the field resized like I wanted, the fields after this, on the page, get crowded together.  It's like the browser is not maintaining the margins and padding after the current change...

[image]
Because of this crowding, I added the line in that event listener that causes not just the textbox to resize, but also the form-group containing it.  On IE, that fixed the spacing problem.  But on Chrome, the form, after the field that was resized, is still getting all crowded like this.

**Question:** Is there a way to tell Bootstrap or the DOM to update the rest of the page appropriately?  Am I missing something?

**UPDATE** - I have created [a PEN to show you this](https://codepen.io/AgapwIesu/pen/qmgGNJ).  I put as little as possible of my css (basically the css asp.net gave me), html and javascript, while still duplicating the problem.  When you go into this pen, start typing into the comments field and see what happens to the vertical spacing of the fields.  Make sure you type multiple lines of text into that comments field.

Comment: Maybe your `ResizeFormGroup();` function is resizing all `.form-group` divs on a page?

Comment: No, that function just goes out to the form-group containing the textbox and resizes that form-group only so its display height is equal to its scroll height. When i take that line of code out, the crowding still happens, on both Chrome and IE. With that line there, the crowding does not happen in IE, but it still happens in Chrome. It's like IE, at least, is smart enough to know that when the form-group gets resized, the rest of the page needs to be updated. But Chrome does not get even that. And neitherone update the rest of the page when just the textbox is resized.

Comment: If you use `<div contenteditable>` you don't need any JS at all. It expands automatically --> [see this example](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/XROQJd)

Comment: do you have a link you can share so I can see this happening?

Comment: Must be something else in that case; looks like `.form-group` elements lost their `margin-bottom` for some reason. I don't think what you have added so far is enough to find the cause. I suggest you creating fiddle with your rendered html and related javascript / css

Comment: I am using asp.net, so not thrilled about trying to use a div for user input, but I tried it anyway.  Basically no formatting gets updated after it.  The bootstrap dressing on the field stays still, so you are typing all over the fields after it... gets ugly.  Not sure that is really a viable thing here.  I did also try just adding the contenteditable attribute to my textbox and the form-group, to no avail.

Comment: Tested on Edge, IE11, Chrome, Mozilla.  Unable to reproduce.  [Tested here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MmLROy).

Comment: i am trying to duplicate on a pen, but not having luck.  I am using asp.net, and am wondering how much the default css and form templates are screwing me up on this.

Comment: Got it duplicated.  See here: https://codepen.io/AgapwIesu/pen/qmgGNJ

Comment: @MichaelCoker - I have added a link to a pen that duplicates the problem.  If you go to it and start typing multiple lines into the comments, you will see just the behavior I am talking about.

Comment: @Morpheus - I created a pen that duplicates the problem, and added the link in my question...

Comment: @AgapwIesu it's because you floated your `.col` classes and didn't clear the float. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GmzbWm

Comment: @MichaelCoker - forgive me if I reveal how much of a newb I am... how do I "clear the float"?

Comment: When you float an element, it removes the element from the flow of the page. So the parent's height will not necessarily respect the height of it's floated children. So your floated `.col-*` classes are overflowing outside of the parent, causing things to look squished. To address that, you need to apply a "clearfix" to the parent element. "clearfix" is just a word for any number of techniques that will clear floated children on a parent element. I added `overflow: auto;` to `.form-group`, and that's one way to clear floated children. Bootstrap also has a `.clearfix` class you can (should) use

Comment: https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/VbgJMm

Comment: I can submit this as an answer if you like and intent on leaving the question open.

Comment: @MichaelCoker - please do submit it as an answer.  I try to stick to whatever framework I am using - in this case asp.net, and that float is what came as default in the css.  I created my forms like it created the default forms, and had this problem.  Based on your advice, I added a clear:left; property to the form-group class, and that fixed the problem.  Thanks a ton.

Comment: @AgapwIesu you're welcome. Are you not using bootstrap? I only mention bootstrap because it's in the codepen you created.

Comment: @MichaelCoker - I am using bootstrap.  That is why I added it to the codepen I created.  Is the "clearfix" class a default class that comes with their css?

Comment: @AgapwIesu *"Is the "clearfix" class a default class that comes with their css?"* yes. You should use their classes over writing your own CSS when possible. It's leaner.

Comment: @MichaelCoker - will do, and thanks again!  You not only solved my problem, but taught me a few things in the process.  Wish I could do more than just say thanks.

Comment: @AgapwIesu sweet! you're welcome.

Comment: If the problem is solved then why are you offering bounty?

Comment: @TalentRunners - to give Michael Coker the reward as a thank you for the very valuable help.  One of the categories for bounties is rewarding existing, good answers.  I just had not given him the bounty yet, because after I posted the bounty, I had to wait at least 24 hours to award it, and it's just now that I got back into SO to get it done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple "clearfix" problem, because you have floated the columns that hold your form fields. Without clearing the float on those fields, the parent rows will not respect the height of the floated children.

There are a number of ways to implement clearfix. Using your bootstrap code, you can simply add a `.clearfix` class to parent rows that have floated children to utilize bootstraps clearfix method. Or you can use `overflow: auto;` on those rows as well or implement your own clearfix class in another way.

```js
        function AutoExpandTextbox(txtbox) {
            txtbox.style.height = "1px";
            txtbox.style.height = (4 + txtbox.scrollHeight) + "px";
        }
```

```css
.col-sm-2, .col-sm-10 {
  float: left;
}
.form-group {
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding-bottom:25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form>
  <div >
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="comments">Comments:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="comments" onkeyup="AutoExpandTextbox(this)"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="field1">Field1:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10"> 
        <input class="form-control" id="field1" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group clearfix">
      <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="field2">Field2:</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10"> 
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="field2">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group clearfix"> 
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```